# Can I always use "with" instead of "because of"? If not when can I use it?

Tags: prepositions

Can I always use with instead of because of? If not when can I use it?

For example, can I say:

> His company went bankrupt with him.

and:

> His fingers are numb with cold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are quite different. In some cases (eg *numb with cold*) "because of" could be substituted, but these are the exception.

In *his company went bankrupt with him* is not clear what relationship between the bankruptcy and him is being stated, but it certainly doesn't naturally suggest that it was because of him.

Most cases where you can use *with* like this are emotions: *I was shaking with fear*; *She was nervous with anticipation*. "Because of" would be possible in these, but not natural.